# Error with the output when using moviepy module to concatenate video files

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, moviepy

I am trying to use moviepy to join some video clips together, I get the output, with the files joined as expected. When watching the final video, clip1 looks as expected but clip2 has an error, see image.
[image]
All resources I have looked at show that the way the code I have written should work, so am unure what I could do to solve the issue. Any suggestion would be amazing!

The code that I used

```
filenames = ['clip1.mp4', 'clip2.mp4', 'clip3.mp4']

for x in range(len(filenames)):
    filenames[x] = VideoFileClip(filenames[x])

final_video = concatenate_videoclips(filenames)
final_video.to_videofile("final_video.mp4", fps=30, codec="mpeg4")
```

Comment: This is the code to concatenate one set of clips, but you said it fails when you try to do multiple sets. Please [edit] your question and show us that code as well.

Comment: @MattDMo it is only one set, They way I wrote the question makes it sound different

Comment: OK, so `clip1.mp4` looks fine in the concatenated version, but `clip2.mp4` and `clip3.mp4` do not, correct? Is `concatenate_videoclips()` a function that you wrote yourself, or did you import it from `moviepy`?

Comment: Nevermind, I'm looking at its [source](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/blob/master/moviepy/video/compositing/concatenate.py) now. Were all of your clips the same dimensions and did they all have the same masks, if any?

Comment: That is correct, clip1 is fine but clip2 and clip3 are not. concatenate_videoclips() is a function that was imported from the moviepy module.

Comment: You need to make them all the same size or use `method=“compose”`

Comment: Thank you, that has fixed it. The issue was that the video dimensions were different.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
filenames = ['clip1.mp4', 'clip2.mp4', 'clip3.mp4']

clips = []

for file in filenames:
    clips.append(VideoFileClip(file))

final_video = concatenate_videoclips(clips, method=compose)
final_video.write_videofile('final_video.mp4', fps=30)
```

Comment: wrong, it's method='compose'